# Как мне в хендлере проверить совпадение текста по списку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как мне в хендлере `text =`  проверить на совпадение по списку `list` ?

```
list = ['Пончик', 'Шоколадка', 'Кофе']

@dp.message_handler(text = 'Тескт')
async def categories(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, text = 'Да, я бы сейчас не отказался', reply_markup = back_kb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть кому-то пригодится...

```
#from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text

list = ['Пончик', 'Шоколадка', 'Кофе']

@dp.message_handler(Text(equals=list))
async def eat_something(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Да, я бы сейчас не отказался')
```